# How to append routerLink attribute from directive?

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 4 and trying to add `routerLink` attribute from my directive. I added `@HostBinding() routerLink = '/foo'` but it causes an error.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myRouterLink]'
})
export class MyRouterLinkDirective {
  // this causes error: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.
  @HostBinding() routerLink = '/foo'
}
```

This is my sample plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/STpwQH?p=preview

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: can i know whats the purpose behind doing this. Actually angular provide `routerLink ` default directive for routing purpose

Comment: I would like to implement a directive that converts `<a [myRouterLink]="urlFromSomeApi">` into `<a routerLink="..." [queryParams]="{...}">`. `urlFromSomeApi` might be `/foo`, `/foo?bar=1` or `http://example.com/`.

Comment: ok that you can directly pass to angular `routerLink directive`. It doesnt seem any purpose of you behind writting your own directive